# How to build a [HttpPost] method in web API for object class? (Xamarin.form + web API)(update1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, http-post, postman

I'm trying to do to a **xamarin.form** to **register an admin account to the web API** combine with the predefined value by entering the value in my XAML and register/post it to web API. Unfortunately, I'm still a beginner in the Xamarin platform.

I'm facing the problem of **make the body of the [HttpPost] method** in **AdminAccountController.cs** for my class object.

(Updated 1)

-Success return a response in Postman when POST requested

POSTMAN GET REQUEST response(succeed):-

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "admin1",
        "password": "12345678"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "admin2",
        "password": "12345678"
    }
]
```

POSTMAN POST REQUEST response (succeed provide by @jason):-

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "admin3",
    "password": "12345678"
}
```

AdminAccountController.cs (Updated)

```
using FoodWebApi.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
namespace FoodWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class AdminAccountController : ApiController
    {
        List<Admin> admins = new List<Admin>()
        {
            new Admin
            {
                id=1,
                username="admin1",
                password="12345678"
            },
            new Admin
            {
                id=2,
                username="admin2",
                password="12345678"
            }
        };
        //http://localhost:53287/api/AdminAccount
        public IEnumerable<Admin> GetAll()
        {
            return admins;
        }
        //http://localhost:53287/api/AdminAccount/1
        public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
            var admin = admins.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
            if (admin == null)
            {
                return NotFound();

            }
            return Ok(admin);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public Admin PostNewAdmin(Admin admin)
        {
            // add the new admin to your list
            admins.Add(admin);

            // return to the caller
            return admin;
        }
    }
}
```

Admin.cs

```
namespace FoodWebApi.Models
{
    public class Admin
    {
        public int id { set; get; }
        public string username { set; get; }
        public string password { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is PostNewAdmin supposed to do?  Based on your code I'd assume that it would just add the `admin` object received from the client to the `admins` array.

Comment: @Jason How to add the admin object and what do I need to return??  I know this is a stupid question, but it made me struggling the whole day.

Comment: I need a simple example to add and return the object in the [HttpPost] method to easy me to learn. I'm had referred many sites for an example, but it was not meet to my requirement which is to return an object in the [HttpPost] method. If have any reference that meets the requirement, you can also help me to attach here. I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, use a List instead of an array, it's just easier

```
    // need this for List
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    ...

    List<Admin> admins = new List<Admin>() 
    {
        new Admin
        {
            id=1,
            username="admin1",
            password="12345678"   
        },
        new Admin
        {
            id=2,
            username="admin2",
            password="12345678"
        }
    };

    [HttpPost]
    public Admin PostNewAdmin(Admin admin)
    {
        // add the new admin to your list
        admins.Add(admin);

        // return to the caller
        return admin;
    }
```